# Mysql Slow Query - Even with all the indices

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
mysql> explain
    select c.userEmail,f.customerId 
    from comments c 
      inner join flows f 
        on (f.id = c.typeId) 
      inner join users u 
        on (u.email = c.userEmail) 
    where c.addTime >= 1372617000 
      and c.addTime <= 1374776940 
      and c.type = 'flow' 
      and c.automated = 0;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                          | key        | key_len | ref                 | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | index  | PRIMARY                                | customerId | 4       | NULL                | 144443 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref    | userEmail_idx,addTime,automated,typeId | typeId     | 198     | f.id,const  |      1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | email                                  | email      | 386     | c.userEmail |      1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+--------+-------------+
```

How do I make the above query faster - it constantly shows up in the slow query logs.
Indexes present :

1. id is the auto incremented primary key of the flows table.
2. customerId of flows table.
3. userEmail of comments table.
4. composite index (typeId,type) on comments table.
5. email of users table (unique)
6. automated of comments table.
7. addTime of comments table.

Number of rows :
1. flows - 150k
2. comments - 500k (half of them have automated = 1 and others have automated = 0)  (also value of type is 'flow' for all the rows except 500)
3. users - 50

Table schemas :

```
 users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 

 comments | CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userEmail` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `addTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `typeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `automated` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userEmail_idx` (`userEmail`),
  KEY `addTime` (`addTime`),
  KEY `automated` (`automated`),
  KEY `typeId` (`typeId`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=572410 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


 flows | CREATE TABLE `flows` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `customerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `flowType_idx` (`type`),
  KEY `customerId` (`customerId`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `createTime` (`createTime`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=134127 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: Try adding an index on `(automated, type, addTime)`

Comment: forgot to mention, there is an index on addTime already.

Comment: Just ran optimize table on comments, explain output show far lesser number of rows now. I will see if it also speeds up the query in application's context.

Comment: It will also help if you redesigned the tables so that they use narrow columns for joining. You currently have `email` which appears to be `VARCHAR(128)`. The indexes used for joining, are 386 bytes wide which isn't exactly the best for efficiency.

Comment: Show your table schema.

Comment: @bmused added schemas.

Comment: How long does this query currently take? What sort of reduction are you looking for?

Comment: try to change the order of tables in join. i recommend :

Comment: @MarkBannister it takes around 2 seconds. I would like to make it less than 1.5 seconds or better.

Answer (score 1):

You have the required indexes to perform the joins efficiently. However, it looks like MySQL is joining the tables in a less efficient manner. The `EXPLAIN` output shows that it is doing a full index scan of the `flows` table then joining the `comments` table.

It will probably be more efficient to read the `comments` table first before joining. That is, in the order you have specified in your query so that the comment set is restricted by the predicates you have supplied (probably what you intended).

Running `OPTIMISE TABLE` or `ANALYZE TABLE` can improve the decision that the query optimiser makes. Particularly on tables that have had extensive changes.

If the query optimiser still gets it wrong you can force tables to be read in the order you specify in the query by beginning your statement with `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN` or by changing the `INNER JOIN` to `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out straight_join. Though I read up somewhere that it's not an ideal solution - but it helped in optimizing another query.